# Determine whether or not the function f it is bijective 2f(3-2x)+f(3/2-x/2)=x, where x is a real number

Tags: functions, functional-equations

So the problem says: Study the bijectivity of the functions f:R->R, which follow the property:

a) $2f(x)+f(1-x)=x-8$; b)$2f(3-2x)+f(\frac{3-x}{2})=x$, where x is a real number for both.

The first one, a), I solved it by substituing $y=1-x=>x=1-y$, gets us the following ecuation:

$2f(1-x)+f(x)=-x-7=>f(1-x)=\frac{-x-7-f(x)}{2}$, and if we substitute this in the first ecuation we get:

$2f(x)+\frac{-x-7-f(x)}{2}=x-8=>4f(x)-f(x)-x-7=2x-16<=>3f(x)=3x-9=>f(x)=x-3$

And this function is indeed bijective. Now, for the second one, b), I don't know what to substitute x with to find the function f. I tried a lot of systems of ecuation with no luck, like $y=\frac{3-x}{2}=>x=3-2y$, which will get us the echivalent functional ecuation: $2f(4y-3)+f(y)=3-2y$, and $y=3-2x=>x=\frac{3-y}{2}$ which will get us to $2f(y)+f(\frac{3-y}{4})=\frac{3-y}{2}$. I don't know what connection to find between these ecuations...

Comment: Note that you're asked to study the bijectivity, as opposed to solving the functional equation. There could be a lot of solutions, which arise from "changing initial values".  EG For infectivity, is it possible that (say) $ f( \pi ) = f(e) = 0$?

Comment: @CalvinLin ,that's true,I only focused on finding the function without paying attention to the statement of the problem. f(π)=f(e)=0,(depends on f). I think I get what you mean, we take one random number x and we get f(x1)+f(x2)=x, a better example would be 2g(4y-3)+g(y)=0,Hence immediately for y = 1 the relation g (1) = 0.
One way to see that we now have an infinite degree of freedom is the following. Note with Ty (without parentheses, T (y) is too complicated) the application Ty = 4y-3. Then this operation has no cycles other than T1 = 1, We cannot have TT ... T y = y for y other than 1.

Comment: Starting with an element x0 we can then consider the string indexed by an n in ZZ, which we obtain by applying recursive T, for n to infinity, respectively the inverse of T (of | n | times) for n to minus infinity ...

In each such string, we choose a special value for g (x0), after which the other values ​​are uniquely defined.

Comment: For example, for every element x0 in [2,5) there is a unique A in [1,4) with the property that x0 = 1 + A. Then the string xn completed recursively by T has the formula

x (n) = 1 + A.4 ^ n.

We define g for the members of this string as follows:

g (x (n)) = Constanta. (-2) ^ n

or something like that. (For each orbit we can take another constant.)
Then the functional equation wants the relationship from us

2g (x (n + 1)) + g (x (n)) = 0

and we just arranged to have

2 (-2) ^ (n + 1) + (-2) ^ n = 0.

Comment: Essentially yes (but I'm not clear what you're doing in the third comment).

Answer (score 2):

On the second equivalent equation you found,

$2f(y)+f(\frac{3-y}{4})=\frac{3-y}{2}$, (1)

use twice the map $x\mapsto (3-x)/2$, ie, let

$z=\frac{3-(\frac{3-y}{2})}{2}=\frac{y+3}{4}$,

$\Rightarrow y=4z-3$.

Plugging this in (1) yields

$2f(4z-3)+f(-z)=3-2z$

and by subtracting what we found from your first equation we can conclude

$f(z)=f(-z)$.

Hence $f$ is not injective, as it's an even function.

Comment: I think my answer is wrong because (1) is wrong; it should be $2f(y)+f(\frac{3+y}{4})=\frac{3-y}{2}$.

Comment: The equivalence classes are distinct and non-repetive, so there's likely an arithmetic error made.